# Problema con HTTPS y font-faces

Tags: https, font-faces

después de activar un certificado *Let´s Encrypt* para usar **HTTPS** en mi sitio web, no consigo que carguen las **@font-faces** y se vean los iconos correctamente. Estoy usando *Firefox* y *Chrome* en sus últimas versiones para las pruebas.

Originalmente (cuando todo funcionaba con HTTP) tenía lo siguiente en mi fichero CSS:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'cl-xxx';
        src: url('../fonts/cl.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/cl.eot')  format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../fonts/cl.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/cl.ttf')  format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/cl.svg')  format('svg');
}
```

Los CSS los tengo en la carpeta "public/css/" y las fuentes en "public/fonts/" y poniendo la siguiente URL en el navegador me baja el fichero fuente: https://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.eot

Si puedo cargar las fuentes de iconos, pero colocando *@font-face { ... }* en la cabecera del documento HTML, no en las hojas de estilo como venía haciendo, y solo funciona si uso rutas relativas o absolutas con "http", con "https", no.

**¿Qué he probado?**

```
1. Al minificar el CSS se eliminan las comillas dentro de url, p.e. url('../fonts/cl.eot'); queda url(../fonts/cl.eot);
Las restaure manualmente.

2. Copiar el directorio de fuentes en el directorio CSS modificando la ruta relativa:

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'cl-xxx';
        src: url('fonts/cl.eot');
        src: url('fonts/cl.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/cl.woff')     format('woff'),
        url('fonts/cl.ttf')      format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/cl.svg')      format('svg');
    }


3. Usar rutas adsolutas para las fuentes, tanto con "http" como con "https", p.e.
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'cl-xxx';
        src: url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.eot');
        src: url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.eot')  format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.woff') format('woff'),
             url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.ttf')  format('truetype'),
             url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.svg')  format('svg');
    }
```

Comment: Si usas apache prueba a agregar en tu `.htaccess` un `FilesMatch`  por cada extensión de fuente que quieras utilizar. Ejemplo:  `<FilesMatch "\.(woff)$">
    Header unset Vary</FilesMatch>`, `<FilesMatch "\.(eot)$">
    Header unset Vary</FilesMatch>`, `<FilesMatch "\.(ttf)$">
    Header unset Vary</FilesMatch>`, `<FilesMatch "\.(svg)$">
    Header unset Vary</FilesMatch>` Si tienes algún plugin de caché y no tienes desactivado que use la caché cuando estás en modo administrador quizá debas limpiar la caché de la página para ver los cambios. Saludos.

Comment: @A. Cedano no me funciono, al poner lo que indicas en el .htaccess no carga la pagina (error 500)

Comment: **A**. Si da error 500 es posible que haya un error de tipeado. Intenta con esto, borrado los anteriores FilesMatch: `<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|svg)">
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>` **B**. ¿Sigues usando las rutas absolutas en el CSS: `src: url('http://www.cambialibros.es/public/fonts/cl.eot');` si es así debería ser `https://` y no `http://`